# Woocommerce checkout page depending on product category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am building on a website using woocommerce.

For some products clients need to write the name of their child in the `Child name` field on the checkout page. (The site sells music lessons)

However for other products like giftcards I dont need this `Child name` field. I can't find any plugin that can show a different checkout page depending on the catagory of the product that the client is buying.

Anyone an idea for making this possible?

Thnx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a website with the answer:

https://wordimpress.com/create-conditional-checkout-fields-woocommerce/

I'm going to try this and place the outcome here.

---

*** okay couple of hours later!
It did the job, the codes in the website I posted are used for a single product ID. If you want to check for category ID you can change this code:

```
 /**
 * Check if Conditional Product is In cart
 *
 * @param $product_id
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function wordimpress_is_conditional_product_in_cart( $product_id ) {
    //Check to see if user has product in cart
    global $woocommerce;

    //flag no book in cart
    $book_in_cart = false;

    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];

        if ( $_product->id === $product_id ) {
            //book is in cart!
            $book_in_cart = true;

        }
    }

    return $book_in_cart;

}
```

for:

```
/**
 * Check if Conditional Product is In cart
 *
 * @param $product_id
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function wordimpress_is_conditional_product_in_cart( $product_id ) {
//Check to see if user has product in cart
global $woocommerce;

//flag no book in cart
$book_in_cart = false;

foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];
        $terms = get_the_terms( $_product->id, 'product_cat' );

            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $_categoryid = $term->term_id;
            }

    if ( $_categoryid === 14 ) {
        //book is in cart!
        $book_in_cart = true;
    }

}

return $book_in_cart;

}
```

If you need to check multiple categorie ID's or product ID's you can copy this excample:

```
/**
 * Check if Conditional Product is In cart
 *
 * @param $product_id
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function wordimpress_is_conditional_product_in_cart( $product_id ) {
//Check to see if user has product in cart
global $woocommerce;

//flag no book in cart
$book_in_cart = false;

foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];
        $terms = get_the_terms( $_product->id, 'product_cat' );

            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $_categoryid = $term->term_id;
            }

    if (( $_categoryid === 14 ) || ( $_categoryid === 16 )) {
        //book is in cart!
        $book_in_cart = true;
    }

}

return $book_in_cart;

}
```

I Hope this post will hopefully save somebody a lot of time searching all the loose bits of information ;)

Answer (score 0):

This worked better for me:

```js
  
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'optional_default_address_fields' );



 function optional_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
 $address_fields['postcode']['required'] = false;
 $address_fields['city']['required'] = false;
 $address_fields['state']['required'] = false;
 $address_fields['address_1']['required'] = false;
 $address_fields['country']['required'] = false;
 $address_fields['billing_company']['required'] = false;

 return $address_fields;
 }
 
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $categories = array('ajakirjad');

    $foundAjakiri = false;
    $foundOthers = false;
    
    
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        
        if(has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] )) {
            $foundAjakiri = true;
        } else {
            $foundOthers = true;
        }
    }
    if($foundAjakiri == true && $foundOthers == false) {
//        echo '1';
    } elseif($foundAjakiri == false && $foundOthers == true) {
        
        $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['required'] = false;
        $fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['required'] = false;
        $fields['billing']['billing_city']['required'] = false;
        $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['required'] = false;
        $fields['billing']['billing_state']['required'] = false;
        $fields['billing']['billing_country']['required'] = false;
        $fields['billing']['billing_country']['class'][] = 'no-need';
        $fields['billing']['billing_company']['required'] = false;
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
        
//        unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
//        unset($fields['billing']['billing_phone']);
        //unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);
    }
    
    //add_filter( 'woocommerce_enable_order_notes_field', '__return_false', 9999 );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'remove_order_notes' );
    
    
    
    return $fields;
}
```